# Combine IMU with visual odometry using rtabmap

Tags: slam, navigation, odometry, visual-odometry, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I want to combine a razor 9dof IMU (package [razor_imu_9dof](http://wiki.ros.org/razor_imu_9dof)) with visual odometry from ASUS Xtion Pro live using rtabmap. I used package [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) to combine 2 data sources. I am confusing about the tf. I still use the visual odometry from rtabmap_ros. The package robot_localization takes data from topic /imu and /rtabmap/odom. In theory the tf from odom to camera_link must be published by robot_localization but it is still published by /rtabmap/rgbd_odometry. Can anyone explain me about the tf which is published by rtabmap/rgbd_odometry and the tf which is published by robot_localization and how to fix my problem or show me how to do the combination, please?

Another question is that when rtabmap/rtabmapviz doesn't subcribe any odometry topic, i still receive the map data, the rtabmapviz gui seems to work well. The only unusual thing is that the odometry display in rtabmapviz gui is black. It made me think the odometry is not important or i misunderstand something? Can anyone explain me, please?

I attached here the TFTree and NodeGraph.

Thank you in advance for your attention to this matter.

[TF Tree http://s14.postimg.org/mtz02ccpd/frames.png](http://s14.postimg.org/mtz02ccpd/frames.png)
[Node Graph http://s7.postimg.org/arsi06e7f/rosgraph.png](http://s7.postimg.org/arsi06e7f/rosgraph.png)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221103/combine-imu-with-visual-odometry-using-rtabmap/) by [VMHOANG68](https://answers.ros.org/users/25111/vmhoang68/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should set `publish_tf` parameter of [rgbd_odometry](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#Visual_Odometry) node to false.

```
<node package="rtabmap_ros" type="rgbd_odometry" name="rgbd_odomerty">
   <param name="publish_tf" type="bool" value="false"/>
   ...
</node>
```

Odometry topic is mandatory for [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap), not for [rtabmapviz](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmapviz). The odometry topic is used by [rtabmap](http://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros#rtabmap) only if `odom_frame_id` parameter is set:

> ~odom_frame_id (string, default: "")

> The frame attached to odometry. If
> empty, rtabmap will subscribe to odom
> topic to get odometry. If set,
> odometry is got from tf (in this case,
> a covariance of 1 is used).

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [VMHOANG68](https://answers.ros.org/users/25111/vmhoang68/) on 2015-11-18**:
Thank you matlabbe, now it is working as I desired.